# Time complexity of function Counter example?

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity

assume i have `n=O(g(n))` so can i assume that then the following is always

gonna happen for every

```
> m=(1,2,3 ... ) --> n=O(g(n^m)) ..
```

(i think this statment is wrong and i am trieng to find a Counter example for it .. any help?

Comment: I think you need to write a bit more for anyone to be able to answer. `O(...)` probably means ordo, but I don't understand what `n=O(g(n))` means.

Comment: g(n) function of n that accepts natural numbers(N->R)

Comment: so n=O(g(n)) means that there is a constant c and n0 that for every n>n0 the following happens : n<= c*g(n)

Comment: The statement is true.  HINT: n < n^m

Comment: but i tried to prove it multiple times but i couldn't so i thgout it is a false statment

Comment: @jasmin I am not going to do your homework for you.  I already gave you a strong leading hint.

Comment: yeah i am just stuck here .. n<=n*n*n...*n<=f(n)*f(n)*...f(n) therefor n<=(f(n)^m)

Comment: oh no what am i doing i need to prove f(n^m) :( i am gonna think more about it

Comment: i didn't figure it out .. could you give me one more hint ?

Comment: The following can be proved directly from the definition.  If `1 = o(f(n))` (ie `f` goes to infinity) and `n = O(g(n))` then `f(n) = O(g(f(n)))`.  Now set `f(n) = n^m`...

Comment: thank you so much i understood my mistakes and you're sulotion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is correct.

Since `n = O(g(n))`, we can also assume `n^m = O(g(n^m))`. Now for `m >= 1`, we get `n = O(n^m)`. In a last step we use the transitivity of Big-O to get `n = O(g(n^m))`.

Comment: If you're going to hand out a full solution without any work required, at least make it cute, simple and direct.  If `N < n` then `n <= n^m <= c * f(n^m)` with the latter step holding because `N < n^m`.

Comment: @btilly can't see much of a difference, apart from the fact that I split up the steps.